# Converting plain JavaScript to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

really simple question, just having a hard time actually making it work.  I have a snipet of code that's javascript that I'm trying to write in jquery and can't quite get it.

```
effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO.style.setProperty('-webkit-transform',   
'rotateZ('+effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG+'deg)');
```

and I had tried it as

```
$("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO").css("-webkit-transform", 
"rotateZ('+effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG+'deg)");
```

but the jquery snippet doesn't work, I'd really appreciate any help I can get on this, I'm sure it'll be breeze for someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG` is another id of an element with a value, try:

```
$("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO").css("-webkit-transform", 
"rotateZ('" + $("#effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG").val() +"'deg)");
```

Comment: Why would you assume that? It is certainly not backed by the original JS code.

Comment: @Thilo - it seems to be OP's naming convention of his id's. But yes, it could also just be a js var. Too little info I guess :)

Answer (score 6):

It should be:

```
$("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO").css("-webkit-transform",
"rotateZ("+effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG+"deg)");
```

you were mixing single quotes with double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO").css("-webkit-transform", "rotateZ('+effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG+'deg)");
```

That doesn't look right. Unless this was a copy-paste error you should split the variable values from the rest of the strings the same way as the JavaScript version had done.

```
$("#effects_of_yoga_2010_INFO").css("-webkit-transform", "rotateZ(" + effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG + "deg)");
```

Of course, this is based on not knowing what `effects_of_yoga_2010_DEG` is. I'm assuming it simply contains the value you are looking for and can be used the same as the JavaScript version had done.